# String breaks on square bracket when parsed with lxml

Tags: python, string, xml-parsing, lxml

I'm new to lxml parsing, and can't manage a simply parsing issue. The is a line in my xml that looks like:

```
The IgM BCR is essential for survival of peripheral B cells [<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="CR34">34</xref>]. In the absence of BTK B cell...
```

So, when I execute the following code:

```
e = open('somexml.xml', encoding='utf8')

tree = etree.parse(e)

titles = tree.xpath('/pmc-articleset/article/front/article-meta/title-group/article-title')

for node in titles:
    text = tree.xpath('/pmc-articleset/article/body/sec/p')

    for node in text:
        content = str(node.text).encode("utf-8")
        s = str(' '.join(lxml.html.fromstring(content).xpath("//text()")).encode('latin1'))
        print (s)
```

the result looks like:

```
The IgM BCR is essential for survival of peripheral B cells ['
```

Even if I just print the node.text without any "join" commands the result looks similar.

How can I skip the square brackets part and recieve a full string? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
e = open('somexml.xml', encoding='utf8')

tree = etree.parse(e)

titles = tree.xpath('/pmc-articleset/article/front/article-meta/title-group/article-title')

for title in titles:
    ps = title.xpath('/pmc-articleset/article/body/sec/p')

    for p in ps:
        text = ''.join(p.itertext())
        print(text)
```

Answer (score 3):

`]. In the absence of BTK B cell...` is the value of the `tail` property of the `<xref>` element. See http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/web/etree-view.html.

There is nothing special about the square brackets; they are just characters.

With `itertext()` you can get the text content of an element and its descendants. `tail` content is included by default. See http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#itertext.

Small demo:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = "<p>TEXT <xref>34</xref>TAIL</p>"
p = etree.fromstring(xml)

print(p.text)
print(''.join(p.itertext()))
print(p.text + p.find("xref").tail)
```

Output:

```
TEXT 
TEXT 34TAIL
TEXT TAIL
```