# Python lxml parser isn't returning the entire text of a <p> element if there's a <xref> in it

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to use lxml to extract the text from all `<p>` elements in a .xml format article. Here's a sample of the article:

```
<title>Continuing Education Activity</title>
        <p>Ebstein anomaly is a rare congenital heart disease that involves the apical displacement of the tricuspid valve with adherence of the septal and posterior leaflets to the myocardium and &#x00022;atrialization of the inlet portion of the right ventricle&#x00022;. It is usually accompanied by tricuspid regurgitation, right ventricular failure, and arrhythmias. Clinical manifestations range from asymptomatic to severe, depending on the degree of tricuspid valve displacement and severity of regurgitation, the effective right ventricular volume, and the associated malformations (i.e., pulmonary valve stenosis, atresia, atrial septal defect, etc.). Arrhythmias are common and protracted due to the likelihood of having accessory pathways, in addition to having right atrial dilatation. Symptomatic patients can present with cyanosis, congestive heart failure, and arrhythmias, with exertional dyspnea being common in older patients. This activity reviews the pathophysiology and presentation of Ebstein's malformation and highlights the role of the interprofessional team in its management.</p>
        <p>
<bold>Objectives:</bold>
<list list-type="bullet"><list-item><p>Describe the pathophysiology of Ebstein anomaly.</p></list-item><list-item><p>Review the clinical presentation of a patient with an Ebstein anomaly.</p></list-item><list-item><p>Outline the approach to the management of patients with Ebstein anomaly, including the indications for non-surgical and surgical intervention.</p></list-item><list-item><p>Summarize the importance of improving care coordination among interprofessional team members to improve outcomes for patients affected by Ebstein anomaly.</p></list-item></list>
<ext-link xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ext-link-type="uri" xlink:href="https://www.statpearls.com/account/trialuserreg/?articleid=20850&#x00026;utm_source=pubmed&#x00026;utm_campaign=reviews&#x00026;utm_content=20850">Access free multiple choice questions on this topic.</ext-link>
</p>
      </sec>
      <sec id="article-20850.s2" sec-type="pubmed-excerpt">
        <title>Introduction</title>
        <p>Ebstein anomaly is a rare congenital abnormality involving the tricuspid valve and the right ventricle (RV),<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="article-20850.r1">[1]</xref>&#x000a0;with an incidence of &#x0003c;1% of congenital heart defects.<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="article-20850.r2">[2]</xref>&#x000a0;It was first described by the pathologist Wilhelm Ebstein in 1866 when he performed an autopsy of a 19-year-old cyanotic&#x000a0;male who had suffered from exertional dyspnea and palpitations and died of a sudden cardiac arrest.<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="article-20850.r3">[3]</xref>&#x000a0;Ebstein anomaly&#x000a0;is defined by the following characteristics:</p>
```

Note how the last `<p>` element has an interspersed `<xref>` element as a citation. When I use the following Python code to extract text:

```
import lxml

def extract_text(filename):

    chunks = []

    tree = etree.parse('./data/statpearls_NBK430685/' + filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    p_tags = tree.findall('.//p')
    # list_tags = tree.findall('.//list')  # whenever there's a list, include the para above as well as context.


    for p in p_tags:
        if p.text is None:
            continue
        elif not any(char.isalpha() for char in p.text): # check that there are some alphabetical characters and ignore if there aren't
            continue

        chunks.append(p.text)

    return chunks

extract_text('article-20850.nxml')
```

And here's the output:

```
 ['Ebstein anomaly is a rare congenital heart disease that involves the apical displacement of the tricuspid valve with adherence of the septal and posterior leaflets to the myocardium and "atrialization of the inlet portion of the right ventricle". It is usually accompanied by tricuspid regurgitation, right ventricular failure, and arrhythmias. Clinical manifestations range from asymptomatic to severe, depending on the degree of tricuspid valve displacement and severity of regurgitation, the effective right ventricular volume, and the associated malformations (i.e., pulmonary valve stenosis, atresia, atrial septal defect, etc.). Arrhythmias are common and protracted due to the likelihood of having accessory pathways, in addition to having right atrial dilatation. Symptomatic patients can present with cyanosis, congestive heart failure, and arrhythmias, with exertional dyspnea being common in older patients. This activity reviews the pathophysiology and presentation of Ebstein\'s malformation and highlights the role of the interprofessional team in its management.',
 'Describe the pathophysiology of Ebstein anomaly.',
 'Review the clinical presentation of a patient with an Ebstein anomaly.',
 'Outline the approach to the management of patients with Ebstein anomaly, including the indications for non-surgical and surgical intervention.',
 'Summarize the importance of improving care coordination among interprofessional team members to improve outcomes for patients affected by Ebstein anomaly.',
 'Ebstein anomaly is a rare congenital abnormality involving the tricuspid valve and the right ventricle (RV),']
```

The last chunk is completely missing all the text after the `<xref>` tag. Anyone know what's going on to cause this behaviour and how this can be prevented?

Comment: You have HTML and you should not be using an XML parse.  HTML and XML are similar (both are Meta Languages) but there are differences and is only some cases you can use the same library to parse.  It is recommended that you use an HTML library to parse you code.

Comment: find out if the `p` tag has children and extract the text from them recursive

Comment: @jdweng I see, thanks. Why would the file extensions be .nxml in this case then?

Comment: The missing text is in the `tail` of the `<xref>` element. There are many similar questions, for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/38462884/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/49921601/407651

Comment: I don't know why @jdweng says that you have HTML. There are no `ext-link`, `bold` or `sec` elements in HTML. Note that the markup you have posted is not well-formed.

Comment: You need to sanitize the XML input and can use XPath like `p_tags = root.xpath("//*[local-name()='p']")`...to iterate...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) library to parse this HTML/XML mixed file:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """\
<title>Continuing Education Activity</title>
        <p>Ebstein anomaly is a rare congenital heart disease that involves the apical displacement of the tricuspid valve with adherence of the septal and posterior leaflets to the myocardium and &#x00022;atrialization of the inlet portion of the right ventricle&#x00022;. It is usually accompanied by tricuspid regurgitation, right ventricular failure, and arrhythmias. Clinical manifestations range from asymptomatic to severe, depending on the degree of tricuspid valve displacement and severity of regurgitation, the effective right ventricular volume, and the associated malformations (i.e., pulmonary valve stenosis, atresia, atrial septal defect, etc.). Arrhythmias are common and protracted due to the likelihood of having accessory pathways, in addition to having right atrial dilatation. Symptomatic patients can present with cyanosis, congestive heart failure, and arrhythmias, with exertional dyspnea being common in older patients. This activity reviews the pathophysiology and presentation of Ebstein's malformation and highlights the role of the interprofessional team in its management.</p>
        <p>
<bold>Objectives:</bold>
<list list-type="bullet"><list-item><p>Describe the pathophysiology of Ebstein anomaly.</p></list-item><list-item><p>Review the clinical presentation of a patient with an Ebstein anomaly.</p></list-item><list-item><p>Outline the approach to the management of patients with Ebstein anomaly, including the indications for non-surgical and surgical intervention.</p></list-item><list-item><p>Summarize the importance of improving care coordination among interprofessional team members to improve outcomes for patients affected by Ebstein anomaly.</p></list-item></list>
<ext-link xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ext-link-type="uri" xlink:href="https://www.statpearls.com/account/trialuserreg/?articleid=20850&#x00026;utm_source=pubmed&#x00026;utm_campaign=reviews&#x00026;utm_content=20850">Access free multiple choice questions on this topic.</ext-link>
</p>
      </sec>
      <sec id="article-20850.s2" sec-type="pubmed-excerpt">
        <title>Introduction</title>
        <p>Ebstein anomaly is a rare congenital abnormality involving the tricuspid valve and the right ventricle (RV),<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="article-20850.r1">[1]</xref>&#x000a0;with an incidence of &#x0003c;1% of congenital heart defects.<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="article-20850.r2">[2]</xref>&#x000a0;It was first described by the pathologist Wilhelm Ebstein in 1866 when he performed an autopsy of a 19-year-old cyanotic&#x000a0;male who had suffered from exertional dyspnea and palpitations and died of a sudden cardiac arrest.<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="article-20850.r3">[3]</xref>&#x000a0;Ebstein anomaly&#x000a0;is defined by the following characteristics:</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

# remove <xref> to not appear in text
for xref in soup.select("xref"):
    xref.extract()

for p in soup.select("p"):
    print(p.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Ebstein anomaly is a rare congenital heart disease that involves the apical displacement of the tricuspid valve with adherence of the septal and posterior leaflets to the myocardium and "atrialization of the inlet portion of the right ventricle". It is usually accompanied by tricuspid regurgitation, right ventricular failure, and arrhythmias. Clinical manifestations range from asymptomatic to severe, depending on the degree of tricuspid valve displacement and severity of regurgitation, the effective right ventricular volume, and the associated malformations (i.e., pulmonary valve stenosis, atresia, atrial septal defect, etc.). Arrhythmias are common and protracted due to the likelihood of having accessory pathways, in addition to having right atrial dilatation. Symptomatic patients can present with cyanosis, congestive heart failure, and arrhythmias, with exertional dyspnea being common in older patients. This activity reviews the pathophysiology and presentation of Ebstein's malformation and highlights the role of the interprofessional team in its management.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Objectives: Describe the pathophysiology of Ebstein anomaly. Review the clinical presentation of a patient with an Ebstein anomaly. Outline the approach to the management of patients with Ebstein anomaly, including the indications for non-surgical and surgical intervention. Summarize the importance of improving care coordination among interprofessional team members to improve outcomes for patients affected by Ebstein anomaly. Access free multiple choice questions on this topic.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Describe the pathophysiology of Ebstein anomaly.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Review the clinical presentation of a patient with an Ebstein anomaly.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Outline the approach to the management of patients with Ebstein anomaly, including the indications for non-surgical and surgical intervention.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Summarize the importance of improving care coordination among interprofessional team members to improve outcomes for patients affected by Ebstein anomaly.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ebstein anomaly is a rare congenital abnormality involving the tricuspid valve and the right ventricle (RV), with an incidence of <1% of congenital heart defects. It was first described by the pathologist Wilhelm Ebstein in 1866 when he performed an autopsy of a 19-year-old cyanotic male who had suffered from exertional dyspnea and palpitations and died of a sudden cardiac arrest. Ebstein anomaly is defined by the following characteristics:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```